# Is there a way two have two different index views on the same controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a situation where I want to set up two different index views from the same controller.

The default view has a table with columns pertaining to incoming stock, while the second one has a table with columns pertaining to the billing for those incoming stock orders.

This separation is to de-clutter the one view I have now that shows all the information on one page.

I plan to switch between them with a button on each view leading to the other.

I realize this is probably not the Rails Way, and if there is such a way to approach this, I'm all ears.

I thought that I could do this using Variants but it seems to me that only works for displaying content to different device types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't understand what you want to achieve ?
If you really want to set up 2 index views, you could do :

```
def index
  if params[:view]
    render 'one_page'
  else
    render 'another_page'
  end
end
```

You could replace param name with what you want.
And when you click on your button to change page, you may do

## config/routes.rb

```
resources :products
```

## index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Next', products_path(view: true) %>
```

That's an option, but I may give you a better answer if I understand better.

Comment: You have the right idea about what I'm trying to do, in fact this is pretty much the exact code I have at the moment in my controller. The problem I'm having is that the second view does not load, and the main view is rendered, so there must be something wrong in the way I'm passing the params to the controller action from my view link. Wait, my first view is still 'index.html.erb', maybe that's the problem. I'll rename it and see what happens.

Comment: Okay I fixed it by changing the if statement to: `if params[:view_name]` dropping the `== "what_you_want"` part, then changing the view link to `<%= link_to 'Next', products_path(view_name: true) %>`. Now it works.

Comment: Nice ! Congratz. I will update my answer then :) Feel free to accept my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering, that let me know I was actually on the right track when I was beginning to think I was way off.